# How to use custom JSON attributes in Chef recipe

Tags: json, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am new to JSON. I have created custom JSON in AWS Opswork and trying to access it as an attribute in Chef recipe, but unfortunately its not catching the JSON values. My JSON file looks like..

```
{

 "normal": { 
 "filebeat_minjar": {
 "log_path" : "/var/log/*.log",
 "hosts" : "Some Random Host ID", 
 "port"  : 5000
 }
 }
}
```

and I am trying to catch it in recipe as,

```
log = node['filebeat_minjar']['log_path']
hosts = node['filebeat_minjar']['hosts']
port = node['filebeat_minjar']['port']
```

But it failed, I have also tried without 'normal'. I got the some []null class error.

Comment: do you maybe man _filebeat_ instead of _filbeat_?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
log = node['normal']['filbeat_minjar']['log_path']
hosts = node['normal']['filbeat_minjar']['hosts']
port = node['normal']['filbeat_minjar']['port']
```

or

```
log = node.normal.filbeat_minjar.log_path
hosts = node.normal.filbeat_minjar.hosts
port = node.normal.filbeat_minjar.port
```

Json object is like a tree, the elements are the branches.
Hope this help

Comment: Do not do this, the node data was malformed and should be fixed instead. Never use the second form for any attribute access, it is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Your Chef code is correct, but you need to fix the JSON. You don't need the `"normal": {...}` in there, Chef and OpsWorks will handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.

Custom JSON

```
{
    "Production": { 
        "ApplicationLayer": {
            "DockerTag" : "Version1"
        }
    }   
}
```

Called from chef recipe.

```
node[:Production][:ApplicationLayer][:DockerTag]
```